# ASP.NET repeater alternate row highlighting without full blown <alternatingitemtemplate/>

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, extension-methods, repeater

I'm trying to accomplish simply adding a css class to a div on alternate rows in my `<itemtemplate/>` without going to the overhead of including a full blown `<alternatingitemtemplate/>` which will force me to keep a lot of markup in sync in the future.

I've seen a solution such as http://blog.net-tutorials.com/2009/04/02/how-to-alternate-row-color-with-the-aspnet-repeater-control/ which I'm tempted to use but this still doesn't "smell" right to me.

Has anyone else got a more maintainable and straightforward solution? Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
<asp:repeater id="repeaterOptions" runat="server">
        <headertemplate>
            <div class="divtable">
                <h2>Other Options</h2>
        </headertemplate>
        <itemtemplate>
                <div class="item <%# IsAlternatingRow ? "dark" : "light" %>">
```

But I can't figure out how to implement `IsAlternatingRow` - even with extension methods.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There is no need to manage your own variable (either an incrementing counter or a boolean); you can see if the built-in [`ItemIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemindex.aspx) property is divisible by two, and use that to set a css class:

```
class="<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "alternate" %>"
```

This has the benefit of being completely based in your UI code (ascx or aspx file), and doesn't rely on JavaScript.

Comment: Fantastic Richard, thats exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! Obviously could have used JS like some of the other answers mentioned but you are correct in saying that is an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: @Richard Ev: Would the code run slower or faster if someone would use ItemTemplate and AlternatingItemTemplate instead of this solution? How could i compare the speed of these two identical codes?

Comment: @Răzvan: Unsure about the performance differences, though I'd warn against premature optimization for something like this.

Comment: For those still coming to this destination, you need to wrap the server-side logic block with single quotes.  Otherwise, you might receive a warning/error about Literal Controls not being allowed

Comment: Late to the party but like others have said great answer! No need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 17):

C#

```
class="<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "alternate" %>"
```

VB

```
class="<%# iif(Container.ItemIndex Mod 2 = 0,"","alternate") %>"
```

Answer (score 6):

This helped me

```
class='<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "alternate" %>'
```

Previous answer resulted in "Server Tag is not well formed" error.

Comment: This is the correct form, when parsing server-side into an HTML Attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the classes with JQuery.

```
$('.divtable > div:odd').addClass('dark');
$('.divtable > div:even').addClass('light');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery instead.  This answer to a previous question may help: [jQuery Zebra selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287489/jquery-zebra-selector)

Comment: This relies on JavaScript being enabled in the browser, which is an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: It depends on the features that are required to work if JavaScript isn't available.  In this case the site will still work but the table will be less readable which I feel is acceptable.

Comment: Good point, though my general approach is to use JavaScript only for things that require it, or that are overly onerous to achieve without it.

In this case it's trivial to achieve table striping without JavaScript, hence my recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Little tweak: the empty class could be removed with something like:

```
  <%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ?  "<tr>" : "<tr class='odd'>"  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for code.  Here's a pure CSS solution:

```
.item:nth-child(odd){background-color: #ccc}
.item:nth-child(){background-color: #ddd}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

IsAlternatingRow can be a protected property and will get set in the ItemDataBound or ItemCreated event.

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsAlternatingRow = !IsAlternatingRow;
}
```