# Set Class Using Eval in Item Data Bound

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, itemdatabound

I have a Repeater item in which their is a tr elements like this.
I want to set css class according to item index as alternating item.

My Design Code is Like This

```
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id='<%# Eval("RegNum").ToString()%>' class='<%# Eval("RowClass").ToString()%>'>
```

Item Data Bound like this but not working: ( Its Wrong )

```
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataBinder.Eval("RowClass", "bgBlack");
        }
        else
        {
            DataBinder.Eval("RowClass", "bgWhite");
        }
```

where bgWhite and bgBlack are css class.

Suggest Me how to achieve this.

Comment: your <tr> tag must be server tage make it <tr runat="server" id='<%# Eval("RegNum").ToString()%>' class='<%# Eval("RowClass").ToString()%>'> it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can see if the built-in ItemIndex property is divisible by two, and use that to set a css class:

```
class="<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "bgWhite" : "bgBlack" %>"
```

This has the benefit of being completely based in your UI code (ascx or aspx file), and doesn't rely on JavaScript.

Please see the below link

[ASP.NET repeater alternate row highlighting without full blown <alternatingitemtemplate/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847806/asp-net-repeater-alternate-row-highlighting-without-full-blown-alternatingitemt)